# 500 Not Found Error When Calling Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting used to using AspNetCore 2.0.

I have a WPF client and it invokes my web api controller.

First this is my Web Api (under core 2.0).

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmailRecordController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ValidateEmail")]
    public EmailRecord ValidateEmail([FromBody] EmailRecord emailRecord)
    {
        return _externalApiEmailService.Search(emailRecord.email);
    }
}
```

I call it from my WPF Client:

```
var uriController = "api/EmailRecord/ValidateEmail";

public async Task<EmailRecord> SearchEmail(
    string emailAddress, string uriController)
{
    //var uri = "http://localhost:49627//api/Email/Search";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49627/");
        var emailRecord = new EmailRecord {email = emailAddress};
        var jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailRecord);
        var contentPost = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uriController, contentPost).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailRecord>(json);
    }
}
```

My Model on my Client is:

```
public class EmailRecord
{
    public string CompanyRef { get; set; }
    public string ClientRef { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string did_you_mean { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string format_valid { get; set; }
    public string mx_found { get; set; }
    public string smtp_check { get; set; }
    public string catch_all { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string disposable { get; set; }
    public string free { get; set; }
    public string score { get; set; }
}
```

My model on my asp.net.core server is:

```
public class EmailRecord
{
    public string CompanyRef { get; set; }
    public string ClientRef { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string did_you_mean { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string format_valid { get; set; }
    public string mx_found { get; set; }
    public string smtp_check { get; set; }
    public string catch_all { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string disposable { get; set; }
    public string free { get; set; }
    public string score { get; set; }
}
```

When it is invoked I get this:

- response    {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
  {
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcREVWLUluZm9ybWVkV29ya2VyXEluZm9ybWVkV29ya2VyXEluZm9ybWVkV29ya2VyXEluZm9ybWVkV29ya2VyXGFwaVxFbWFpbFJlY29yZFxWYWxpZGF0ZUVtYWls?=
  Date: Sun, 10 Dec 2017 19:58:02 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
  }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

I have a similar api (just using a different model/function) and that works Ok and I have used that as a template for all others.

Just cannot see why this is an error?

Additional:

Screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: There should be some additional information in the error response, you haven't given enough information to let us fix it. Are you sure that `_externalApiEmailService.Search` works?

Comment: I shall run it again and do another quickwatch. That metod I have set a breakpoint before it runs any thing but I shall get it to return a null just in case the debugger break-point is not work - though it does on my other api

Answer (score 3):

@People. the reason this erred was that my API controller constructor was accepting and interface but I have not injected it via my StartUp.cs,  So, to illustrate my shame in such a short-falling I shall leave this question up for people to view it!

Comment: you saved me bro .. I was blindly creating core web api keeping web api in mind .. you opened my eyes ... I have to be more careful

Comment: How did you fix this? I have the same problem. but I have registred my interfaces and classes in ninject

Answer (score 2):

A 500 response status code normally means that an exception was thrown (and not handled) while processing the request - that could be anything from a `NullReferenceException` to an error connecting to a database.

To figure out what the issue is you need to capture the exception. I suggest reading [Introduction to Error Handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) for some pointers, the simplest way will probably be to use the developer exception page (top section in that link).

Comment: Thanks this looks a very good link, I shall educate myself. I shall reply to DavidG and reply back shortly.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Justin 's answer, I found an false routing attribute in your Code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmailRecordController : Controller
{
    // you should add the Part-route-template here:
    [HttpPost("ValidateEmail")]
    // If you leave this, your path is localhost:port/validateemail [Route("ValidateEmail")]
    public EmailRecord ValidateEmail([FromBody] EmailRecord emailRecord)
    {
        return _externalApiEmailService.Search(emailRecord.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i have put that in but still get the same error